# jQuery/JavaScript validate City, State ZIP single field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an input field that is for City, State (two letter) and ZIP (5 numeric digits). The format is 'City, State ZIP'.

Would anyone be able to provide how I can validate this format and characters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular expression: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/AeKdj/.

```
/[\w ]+, \w{2} \d{5}/
```

Where:

```
[\w ]+   means more than one of letter or space
\w{2}    means exactly two letters
\d{5}    means five digits
```

E.g.

```
/[\w ]+, \w{2} \d{5}/.test(textbox.value);
```

Comment: `[a-z ]+` should probably be `[\w ]+`, to allow for city names that have accented characters or quotes (although I'm not sure if there are such cities in US).